# Marklogic - get list of all unique document structures in a Marklogic database

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I want to get a list of all distinct document structures with a count in a Marklogic database.

e.g. a database with these 3 documents:

1) <document><name>Robert</name></document>
2) <document><name>Mark</name></document>
3) <document><fname>Robert</fname><lname>Smith</lname></document>

Would return that there are two unique document structures in the database, one used by 2 documents, and the other used by 1 document.

I am using this xquery and am getting back the list of unique sequence of elements correctly:

```
for $i in distinct-values(for $document in doc()
return <div>{distinct-values(
for $element in $document//*/*/name() return   <div>{$element}</div>)}   </div>)
return $i
```

I appreciate that this code will not handle duplicate element names but that is OK for now.

My t questions are:

1) Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? I am assuming yes.
2) Is there a way to get back enough detail so that I could build up the xml tree of each unique structure?
3) What is the best way to return the count of each distinct structure e.g. 2 and 1 and in the above example

Comment: If someone ahs provided a sufficient solution, please mark an answer as accepted. Otherwise, please elaborate on the question so that others may assist.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite list of elements for which you need to do this for, consider co-occurance or other similiar solutions: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences

This requires a range index on each element in question.

MarkLogic works best to use indexes whenever possible. The other solution I can think of is that you actually create a hash/checksum for the values of the target content for each document in question and store this with the document (or in a triple if you happen to have a licence for semantics). Then you you would already have a key for
 the unique combinations.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is looking for unique document structure, and ignoring values.

Comment: Correct. I am not concerned about the element values, just the structure.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? I am assuming yes.

If it were up to me, I would create the document structured in a consistent fashion (like you're doing), then hash it, and attach the hash to each document as a collection.  Then I could count the docs in each collection.  I can't see any efficient way (using indexes) to get the counts without first writing to the document content or metadata (collection is a type of metadata) then querying against the indexes.

> 2) Is there a way to get back enough detail so that I could build up the xml tree of each unique structure?

After you get the counts for each collection, you could retrieve one doc from each collection and walk through it to build an empty XML structure.  XSLT would probably be a good way to do this if you already know XSLT.

> 3) What is the best way to return the count of each distinct structure e.g. 2 and 1 and in the above example

Turn on the collection lexicon on your database.  Then do something like the following:

for $collection in cts:collections()
return ($collection, cts:frequency($collection))

Comment: Thanks, the hashing/collections works well for getting a count and (much) more efficiently checking for unique xml structures in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow exactly what you are after, but I am wondering if this is more what you are looking for- `functx:distinct-element-paths($doc)`

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_distinct-element-paths.html

Here's a quick example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";

let $doc := <document><fname>Robert</fname><lname>Smith</lname></document>

return 
    functx:distinct-element-paths($doc)
```

Outputs the following strings (which could be parsed, of course):

```
document
document/fname
document/lname
```

Answer (score 0):

there are existing 3rd party tools that may work, depending on the size of the data, and the coverage required (is 100% sampleing needed).
Search for "Generate Schema from XML"    -- 
Such tools will look at a sample set and infer a schema (xsd, dtd, rng etc). 
They do an accurate job, but not always in the same way a human would.
If they do not have native ML integration then you need to expose a service or exort the data for analysis.

Once you HAVE a schema, load it into MarkLogic, and you can query the schema (and elements validated by it) directly and programmatically in ML 
If you find a 'generate schema' tool that is implemented in XSLT, XQuery, or JavaScript you may be able to import and execute it in-server.